# update options without reseting the zoom

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using React ApexChart in order to show off some data, and I have a switch that shows and hides the data labels. The options are changing without problems, but the zoom level is resetting every time. Is there a way to keep the zoom level when changing the options?

Here is a small preview of the component:

```
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Layout } from "antd";

interface Props {
  series?: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chartOptiosn?: Record<string, any>;
  [ key: string ]: any;
}

export const DynamicChart: React.FC<Props> = React.memo( ( props: Props ) => {
  const { Content } = Layout;
  const { series, chartOptions, uuid } = props;
  const [ initialRerender, setInitialRerender ] = useState( false );

  useEffect( () => {
    if ( !initialRerender ) {
      setInitialRerender( true );
    }
  }, [ initialRerender ] );

  useEffect( () => {
  }, [] );


  useEffect( () => {
    console.log( chartOptions );
  }, [ chartOptions ] );


  return (
    <Layout>
      <Content>
        <Chart
          options={ { ...structuredClone( chartOptions || {} ), chart: { ...chartOptions.chart, id: uuid } } }
          series={ series }
          type="area"
          height={ 350 }
        />
      </Content>
    </Layout>

  );
} );
```

Here are the options:

```
export const defaultOptions: ApexCharts.ApexOptions = {
  series: [],
  chart: {
    animations: {
      enabled: true,
      easing: "linear",
      dynamicAnimation: {
        speed: 300
      }
    },
    toolbar: {
      show: true,
      tools: {
        download: `<svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable: "false" name= "download" theme="outlined"><path d="M505.7 661a8 8 0 0012.6 0l112-141.7c4.1-5.2.4-12.9-6.3-12.9h-74.1V168c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-60c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v338.3H400c-6.7 0-10.4 7.7-6.3 12.9l112 141.8zM878 626h-60c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v154H214V634c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-60c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v198c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h684c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V634c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8z"></path></svg>`,
        selection: false,
        zoom: true,
        zoomin: true,
        zoomout: true,
        pan: true,
        customIcons: []
      },
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontWeight: 600,
        colors: [ "#8c8c8c" ],
      },
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  }
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-glitter-gqdgf3?file=/src/LineChart/wrapper.tsx) is a demo for more depth of the problem that I am facing.

Just zoom in between the 3 seconds interval and after the labels reappear, the zoom is refreshed. Is there a way to stop that in react, or should I seek a vanilla approach and ditch the react solution all together?

Comment: Please notify me if you have or not access to the link.